# get associated emoji for telegram sticker

Tags: emoji, telegram, telegram-bot

**situation**

my telegram bot receives sticker, say the first one with dog image from `Animals` pack.

**desired result**

write to log file `"user id %d sent sticker: "`

**question**

how to get associated emoji for telegram sticker?

AFAIK, every sticker has some associated emoji.  However bot API does not provide this information.  I saw [telegram TL schema](https://core.telegram.org/schema) but i found the sticker part not well-documented, and i don't have any idea how to use it from python anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [today](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#recent-changes), emoji associated with the sticker is available in the `Sticker` object:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sticker

Comment: they heard my question (: